# Using the value recieved from within a click handler that is inside a ajax request outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

It was suggested that I try to explain my problem with no code so here it goes. I have a webpage that lists a bunch of links with project names as seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz5ZB/1/). What I want to do next is display a second webpage after a project link is clicked by a user. The second webpage would need to make a second ajax request like in this [Second page jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KS3dD/) to get new information to display a project summary, citations and names for that particular project. The part that's killing me is the ajax request for the second page currently has a number 504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b in the url which means it will only use that project for the second page to display summary, citations and names. I need that ajax request to take a variable for any id number. However to compound the problem the id number comes from a user clicking a link on the first page. So my problem is getting the value of the id once a link is clicked and putting it into the ajax request for the next page. I have all the work done for what the pages will display but I can't get the value from the one file to the next. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

wouldn't let me save without putting some code so this is just the bare bones,

```
// The ajax request is in another file but it works good
promise.done(function (json) {
    // Make some links

    // Which link was clicked? I need to see some id please
    $('#sbItems a').on('click', function (e) {  
        e.preventDefault();                      

        // Do stuff to find the id for the link the user clicked

        // Assign the id to a variable that I can use in the next ajax request
        // that is called in a seperate file
        testId = json.items[itemId].id;



    }); // END Click event  

}).fail(function() {
    alert("Ajax call failed!");
});

second file has,

// Need to somehow, someway get the testId variable that holds the id
// into this file

var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/ + THE TESTID + ?format=
jsonp&fields=relationships,title,body,contacts';    
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    complete: onComplete,
    success: function(json) {  
        // Display some stuff based off this url
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get a number from the first page and into the second page when you click a link that takes you to the second page so you can use it in the second page ajax call, then there are several options:

1. Attach the value onto the URL when requesting the second page as a search parameter like this: http://www.sample.com/mypage?id=504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b.  The in the second page, parse that id value out of the URL and use it for your ajax call.  This is the safest of these three options because it works properly even if the user has multiple windows open clicking on different pages in your site.
2. When clicking on the link in the first page, store the id value as a cookie.  In the second page, retrieve the id from the cookie.
3. Same as option 2, but store the value in local storage.

Comment: that's a great idea but I'm still a little confused. So when I'm requesting the second page I'm just using a html file for the second page to display like window.open('Citations.html', '_self');

Comment: When the link is clicked I want the citations.html file to open which will have the new ajax request with the new id in it.

Comment: @jc72 - Then, use `window.open('Citations.html?id=504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b', '_self');` and parse the id value out of its own `window.location.href` URL in the second page's javascript.

Comment: WOW, thanks f^*$ing GENIUS!!!!! I'm embarrased to say how long I've been working on this haha. It looks like that should work, I'm going to parse it and I'll let you know if I have any trouble.

Comment: jfriend00 don't even know how I could repay you for the help seriously was a great answer if I do say so myself!! It works great I just substring'd what I didn't need an plugged it into the full code without really testing and I can get the information for any individual link that's selected. Thanks so much! Also I had no clue that you could just attach something to the html doc name, really that's all it took haha crazy.